# using a radio group in a extjs grid

Tags: extjs

I was using a `new Ext.grid.CheckColumn` in my EXTJS `FlexGridPanel`
 Now the column of checkboxes do not allow multiple selections , so I need to replace it with a column of radio buttons. 
Is it possible to make the CheckColumn as single-select?
If not, how can I put the column of radio buttons. In this link, it seems like the grid does not support radio buttons.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel

I say this because there is `CheckboxSelectionModel` but no `RadioButtonSelectionModel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CheckboxSelectionModel has a property `singleSelect`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks. But if there is a column of checkboxes, setting singleselect:true does not prevent you from checking multiple checkboxes.

Comment: Then it's a bug, because documentation says it should: true to allow selection of only one row at a time (defaults to false allowing multiple selections) ...`

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using? Previous comment was intended for 3.4 (make sure you use single_S_elect). If you're on 4.0 it will be different - selection model has property mode: SINGLE for such behaviour