# Only one checked checkbox allowed in a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Is it possible to have a `CheckboxColumn` in a grid panel that can be checked on only one row at a time ?

I've tried Googling what I'm looking for and I'm not finding much.

Do I need to do something at the store level and at the grid level ? I'm halfway through coding a logic that does it using the `checkchange` event, but I wondered if I'm writing useless code :)

Thank you.

Comment: Halfway? Then you must have written about 4 lines of code already :)

Comment: Will it be possible to use radio button? That will save you all coding :) and it is meant to solve the kind of problem that you are solving right now.

Comment: @khagesh ExtJS does not have a radio button column

Comment: @FrancisDucharme take a look at these links. It might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539284/using-a-radio-group-in-a-extjs-grid and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542961/ext-js-grid-having-one-column-of-radio-buttons

Comment: @khagesh Thanks, I used the radio box tweak in the 2nd link

Answer (score 0):

Your best option as suggested in the comments is to use radio buttons.
The key is to give them all the same name. For example:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="firstname" id="Fred">
<input type="radio" name="firstname" id="Joe">
</form>
```

Then, when one of these radio buttons is selected, any other radio button with the same name will be unselected.